# How to work with different Encoding for Foreign Languages

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, encoding, gensim

I've got a Word Embedding File called `model.txt`. This contains 100 Dimensional vectors for over a million French words. These words contain accented characters such as *é, â, î or ô*.

Let me explain my problem with the following example:
Consider these two words and their respective vectors, both of which are taken from `model.txt`:

```
etait -0.100460 -0.127720 ... 

était 0.094601 -0.266495 ...
```

Both words signify the same meaning but the former is without the accents while the later has accents.

Now I'm trying to load this word embedding using the `gensim.models.KeyedVectors` in the following way:

```
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(open(model_location, 'r',
                                              encoding='utf8'),
                                          binary=False)
word_vectors = model.wv
```

To which I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-e17c33c552da> in <module>
     10 model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(open(model_location, 'r',
     11                                               encoding='utf8'),
---> 12                                           binary=False)
     13 
     14 word_vectors = model.wv

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py in load_word2vec_format(cls, fname, fvocab, binary, encoding, unicode_errors, limit, datatype)
   1547         return _load_word2vec_format(
   1548             cls, fname, fvocab=fvocab, binary=binary, encoding=encoding, unicode_errors=unicode_errors,
-> 1549             limit=limit, datatype=datatype)
   1550 
   1551     @classmethod

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\utils_any2vec.py in _load_word2vec_format(cls, fname, fvocab, binary, encoding, unicode_errors, limit, datatype, binary_chunk_size)
    286                 vocab_size, vector_size, datatype, unicode_errors, binary_chunk_size)
    287         else:
--> 288             _word2vec_read_text(fin, result, counts, vocab_size, vector_size, datatype, unicode_errors, encoding)
    289     if result.vectors.shape[0] != len(result.vocab):
    290         logger.info(

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\utils_any2vec.py in _word2vec_read_text(fin, result, counts, vocab_size, vector_size, datatype, unicode_errors, encoding)
    213 def _word2vec_read_text(fin, result, counts, vocab_size, vector_size, datatype, unicode_errors, encoding):
    214     for line_no in range(vocab_size):
--> 215         line = fin.readline()
    216         if line == b'':
    217             raise EOFError("unexpected end of input; is count incorrect or file otherwise damaged?")

D:\Anaconda\lib\codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    320         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    321         data = self.buffer + input
--> 322         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    323         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    324         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 7110-7111: invalid continuation byte
```

which I thought made sense if my file was encoded in a different format. However, using git I tried checking the encoding of the file using `file *` and got:

```
model.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
```

Now, if I try to write the above code and have the encoding set to `latin1`, there isn't any problem to load this document but at the cost of not being able to access any of the words which contains an accent. Essentially throwing an out-of-vocab error upon executing:
`word_vectors.word_vec('était')`

How am I supposed to approach the problem? I've also got the `.bin` file of the model, should I try to use that to load my words and their corresponding vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, the solution was trivial. Since I had the `.bin` file I could just open it in binary form. If somebody doesn't really have the `.bin` file, they could consider converting the `.txt` file to `.bin` and solve further.